# Passing an argument with all it's attribute VBA

Tags: excel, vba, parameter-passing

Hello to the community.

I want to pass all the attributes of an argument into a SUB:

```
sub MainProcedure
For Each cell In Range("A1:" & LastCol & Lastrow)
FormatCheck (cell)
next cell
end sub
 
Sub FormatCheck(cell As variant)
                    'Check for each cell if it contains a formula
                    If cell.HasFormula = True Then
                        S_ReportError 
                    End If
end sub
```

Unfortunately, just the value of "cell" is passed to the argument and HasFormula(among other attribute) are not transfered to the FormatCheck Sub.
Can you please help on this matter ?

Comment: `Cell As Range`. Also drop the parentheses: `FormatCheck cell`. Also the `= True` is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: Sub FormatCheck(cell As Range)
If cell.HasFormula Then
End If
End Sub
Sub test()
For Each cell In Range("A1:b6")
FormatCheck cell
Next
End Sub

->>>ByRef argument type missmatch

Comment: `Dim cell As Range` within `test`. You really need to declare your variables. Can't hurt to add a `ByVal` too: `Sub FormatCheck(ByVal cell As Range)`.

Comment: Solved quickly and efficiently :)

Comment: Sub FormatCheck(ByVal cell As Range)
                    If cell.HasFormula Then
                    End If
End Sub
Sub test()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In Range("A1:b6")
FormatCheck cell
Next
End Sub

Comment: Just remove parenthesis in `FormatCheck (cell)`